# Binding Activity to the LifecycleOwner with Dagger

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm creating a lifecycle aware class (that will be injected in the activity). It takes two params - event bus and lifecycle owner. 
In that case can I bind activity to the lifecycleowner?

My lifecycle aware class:

```
class Bus @Inject constructor(
        private val eventBus: EventBus,
        private val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) : LifecycleObserver { ... }
```

The binding in my module:

```
@Binds
abstract fun bindLifecycle(activity: SampleActivity): LifecycleOwner
```

And then I'm injecting the Bus in ActivityX as usual:

```
@Inject
lateinit var bus: Bus
```

I'm getting the following error:
ActivityX cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.

So my question: is my approach correct OR it's not possible, since activities DON'T support constructor injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Binds` annotation "ties" a dependency that is **already provided** by `Dagger` to some other type.

By using:

```
@Inject
lateinit var bus: Bus
```

you're not making `SampleActivity` a Dagger dependency (so it is **not** provided by `Dagger`). It only **uses** dependencies provided by `Dagger` so it cannot be used with `@Binds` annotation.

You should have an `ActivityModule` that can expose a `LifecycleOwner` as a dependency:

```
@Module
class ActivityModule(private val activity: AppCompatActivity) {

    @Provides
    fun provideLifecycleOwner(): LifecycleOwner {
        return activity
    }
}
```

(*remember that the class that will use a `LifecycleOwner` must share the scope with the component that uses `ActivityModule`*)

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks for the clarification.